# Pre-pruning a decision tree using the sample_weights

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am running a regression tree using scikit-learn. There are various options for pre-pruning the tree such as `max_depth` or `min_samples_leaf` or `min_samples_split`. However these methods are only applicable to an unweighted decision tree i.e. where `sample_weights` is unspecified.

I am looking for a method that lets you pre-prune the tree using the `sample_weights`. So, for example, any node will become a leaf whenever the total sample weights at that node is less than a prespecified number.

How can I do this? Does `scikit-learn` have a built in procedure that does this?

Comment: what about preprocessing your data to create a new dataset that incorporates the sample weights as actual sample counts? and then use a regular regression tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier):

> class sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(*, criterion='gini',
> splitter='best', max_depth=None, min_samples_split=2,
> min_samples_leaf=1, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, max_features=None,
> random_state=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
> class_weight=None, ccp_alpha=0.0)

the line:

> min_weight_fraction_leaffloat, default=0.0 The minimum weighted
> fraction of the sum total of weights (of all the input samples)
> required to be at a leaf node. Samples have equal weight when
> sample_weight is not provided.

should help you.